# Upload Excel Document From specific IP Address with multiple Sheets

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I want to Upload a file from the Path given which should be a IP Address and search a Excel file there and Upload in to a Database.

The Excel File will have multiple Sheets to be Uploaded.
I also want to store different sheets in to different tables in Database.

How Can I do this in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

If you Are using FTP server Means write like below.The below sample is working fine  with out database.

## FtpWebRequest

```
string CompletePath = "C:/Doc/test.xlsx"; //path for file
private FtpWebRequest FTPDetail(string FileName)
{
string uri = "";
string serverIp = "255.255.255.1"; //Ftp server IP address
string Username = "test"; // Ftp User name
string Password = "test123"; // Ftp Password
uri = "ftp://" + serverIp + "/root/" + FileName;

FtpWebRequest objFTP;
objFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
objFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
objFTP.UsePassive = true;
objFTP.KeepAlive = false;
objFTP.Proxy = null;
objFTP.UseBinary = false;
objFTP.Timeout = 90000;
return objFTP;
}
```

## Upload file

```
public bool UploadFile()
{
FtpWebRequest objFTP= null;
try
{
objFTP= FTPDetail("File.xlsx");
objFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(CompletePath))
{
byte[] buff = new byte[fs.Length];
using (Stream strm = objFTP.GetRequestStream())
{
contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
while (contentLen != 0)
{
strm.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
}
objFTP = null;
}
}
return true;
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
if (objFTP!= null)
{
objFTP.Abort();
}
throw Ex;
}
}
```